# Why won't my UI update while a background task is running?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, compose-desktop

I have this code that should show a counter while a background task is running:

```
@Composable fun startIt() {
  val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
  val running = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
  Button({ scope.launch { task(running) } }) {
    Text("start")
  }
  if (running.value) Counter()
}

@Composable private fun Counter() {
  val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
  LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
     while (true) {
       delay(100.milliseconds)
       count.value += 1
     }
  }
  Text(count.toString())
}

private suspend fun task(running: MutableState<Boolean>) {
  running.value = true
  coroutineScope {
    launch {
      // some code that blocks this thread
    }
  }
  running.value = false
}
```

If I understand correctly, the `coroutineScope` block in `task` should unblock the main thread, so that the `LaunchedEffect` in `Counter` can run. But that block never gets past the first `delay`, and never returns or gets cancelled. The counter keeps showing 0 until the task finishes.

How do I allow Compose to update the UI properly?

Answer (score 0):

`coroutineScope` doesn't change the coroutine context, so I think you're launching a child coroutine that runs in the same thread.

The correct way to synchronously do blocking work in a coroutine without blocking the thread is by using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`:

```
private suspend fun task(running: MutableState<Boolean>) {
  running.value = true
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // some code that blocks this thread
  }
  running.value = false
}
```

If the blocking work is primarily CPU-bound, it is more appropriate to use `Dispatchers.Default` instead, I think because it helps prevent the backing thread pool from spawning more threads than necessary for CPU work.

Comment: From [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#scope-builder): `(...)  coroutineScope just suspends, releasing the underlying thread for other usages`. Am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: The issue is that if your current coroutine context has a single-threaded dispatcher (in this case Dispatchers.Main), then even though `coroutineScope` suspends, it starts using that same thread, effectively blocking anyway. If you changed that inner launch to use `Dispatchers.IO`, it should prevent the blocking. But you don't need `coroutineScope` in the first place unless you are trying to do parallel tasks inside it. It's overkill if you have only one task running inside it. [Example on playground](https://pl.kotl.in/WP5SYEZE4)

Answer (score -1):

This was a small issue of the way count was being modified, and not of coroutines. To fix your code, the remember for count in Counter() needed to be updated to :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
@Composable private fun Counter() {
    val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            delay(Duration.milliseconds(100))
            count.value += 1
        }
    }
    Text(count.value.toString())
}
```

Remember can be done with delegation to remove the need of using the `.value` such as:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalTime::class)
@Composable private fun Counter() {
    var count by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        while (true) {
            delay(Duration.milliseconds(100))
            count += 1
        }
    }
    Text(count.toString())
}
```

Compose does coroutines slightly differently than Kotlin would by default, this is a small example that shows a bit more of how Compose likes Coroutines to be done:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Compose_coroutinesTheme {
                Surface(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    BaseComponent()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// BaseComponent holds most of the state, child components respond to its values
@Composable
fun BaseComponent() {
    var isRunning by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val composableScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center, horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
        Text("Count: ${count.value}")

        // Using the async context of a button click, we can toggle running off and on, as well as run our background task for incrementing the counter
        ToggleCounter(isRunning) {
            isRunning = !isRunning

            composableScope.launch {
                while (isRunning) {
                    delay(100L)
                    count.value += 1
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

// Accepting an onTap function and passing it into our button, allows us to modify state as a result of the button, without the button needing to know anything more
@Composable
fun ToggleCounter(isRunning: Boolean, onTap: () -> Unit) {
    val buttonText = if (isRunning) "Stop" else "Start"
    Button(onClick = onTap) {
        Text(buttonText)
    }
}
```

Comment: The only difference I see is that you're using `by` for the counter state, so don't need to use `.value` for the assignment. Why would that make a difference?

Comment: The biggest change is in the Text(), where it is just `count.toString()` instead of `count.value.toString()`. The `by` or assignment has minimal impact. That is just my preference of usage showing